# When you get an answer and you found out that your problem was different but the given answer would fix the stated problem

Tags: discussion

So I asked a question on fixing a boot loop on my nexus 7. I was given an answer that would fix my problem, but I found out that my problem was different then I stated in my question.  However the answer did give a correct answer for my question. So what do I do? Remove the question or hit correct answer on the person who answered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First thing to ensure is that you don't edit the question to alter its meaning.  Invalidating answers like that is discouraged.  (If you hadn't had any answers, it would be fine.)

It's up to you whether to accept the answer, but generally you should only do so if you're in a position to verify that it works.  If your problem is different, that might not be possible.

If you think the "real" problem and solution would be useful to others, then consider posting them as a separate Q&A (answering your own questions is encouraged).  You might want to do a brief search first to see if there is an existing question that matches which you could answer instead.

Comment: Additionally to posting a new question, I'd suggest to link from there to the original question (and optionally back) for context provided that makes sense – which it usually will, as others might tap into the same trap confusing one issue with the other.